# Changing regular momentary switch to a motion detector in staircase timer circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, motion

(Reference image below)

[image]

I have a classic staircase timer circuit ("**TC**") where any of the momentary switches will trigger the timer to power all the bulbs. Now I want to replace **one** of the "T" switches with a motion detector (**detector**). However, the detector has three terminals (see below)

[image]

where `L` is the input voltage and `A` the output voltage.

**TC**'s `4` goes to **detector**'s `L` though I'm not sure whether I should simply connect **detector**'s `A` to **TC**'s `N` and leave **detector**'s `N` unconnected or should I first short **detector**'s `A` and `N` and then connect them together to **TC**'s `N`.

Comment: Why don't you tell make/model of detector and link to datasheet and manual to see how it operates and if it is even suitable for replacing a pushbutton in your case.

Comment: @Justme sure thing https://b2b.orno.pl/download-resource/26132/

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, the sensor needs Live and Neutral to get power and work.

The load (lamp) is connected betwee Neutral and A terminals, which means the sensor A terminal outputs Live when activated.

Your pushbuttons are wired to connect timer trigger to Neutral to activate it.

Connecting A as pushbutton would do damage. These items are not directly compatible.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect the motion detector in parallel with timer. N to neutral, L to power , A to bulb or terminal 3 of timer. power of motion has to be on same breaker as timer,